# How to return 'year' from the date if the date format is (dd-mm-yyyy) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

1. I am trying to show the dates in **(YYYY-MM-DD)** format which is stored in **(DD-MM-YYYY)** format in the table.
2. Also please explain how to use **year()** function on **(DD-MM-YYYY)** date format.

Comment: Fix the date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your data type is a string then you could use

for format(DD-MM-YYYY)

```
 select year(str_to_date(yourcol, '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

or for format (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
 select year(str_to_date(yourcol, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: `year(str_to_date(yourcol, '%Y-%m-%d')` Eh?

Comment: year(str_to_date(yourcol, '%d-%m-%y'));  worked for me. Note: Use d,m,y in lower case otherwise it returns null

Comment: @SOURABH   %Y  is for YYYY  while  %y is YY  .. so this depend  on your real content